# How can I include unique variables in AWS SES emails when bulk sending?

Tags: amazon-ses

I'm sending bulk emails via AWS SES and need to include unique variables (such as an unsubscribe link) per-recipient. The body of the email changes for each bulk send, but is the same for all recipients with the exception of these few variables.

The obvious solution is to create an SES template that's more or less empty and include the global `DefaultTemplateData` property that includes the body of my email, and then `ReplacementTemplateData` for each recipient that includes their unique variables. Is this the best way to go about it? Feels a bit overkill and I wonder if I'm mis-using the feature.

I currently do this at SendGrid via their "personalizations" functionality. I issue a bulk send request that includes the content of the email along with an array of recipients and unique variables for each of them, ex:

```
sg.sendMultiple({
    subject: 'Hello',
    html: '<div>Have a {{favColor}} {{favFruit}}.</div>'
    from: 'foo@example.com',
    personalizations: [
        {
            to: 'bar@example.com',
            substitutions: {
                favColor: "red",
                favFruit: "apple",
            },
        },
        {
            ...
        },
    ],
});
```

Open to recommendations.